# MySQL loans, payments and clients

Tags: mysql, payment

I have 3 tables "clients", "loans" and "payments"

**TABLE CLIENTS:**

```
+------------+-------------+
| id_client  | name        |
+------------+-------------+
| 1          | James       |
| 2          | Robert      |
| 3          | Michael     |
+------------+-------------+
```

**TABLE LOANS:**

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| id_loan     | id_client   | date_loan   | amount_loan |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1           | 2           | 2020-07-01  | 3000000     |
| 2           | 3           | 2021-07-12  | 2000000     |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

**TABLE PAYMENTS:**

```
+-------------+-------------+--------------+----------------+
| id_payment  | id_loan     | date_payment | amount_payment |
+-------------+-------------+--------------+----------------+
| 1           | 1           | 2020-08-03   | 50000          |
| 2           | 1           | 2020-09-03   | 50000          |
| 3           | 1           | 2020-10-03   | 50000          |
| 4           | 1           | 2020-11-03   | 50000          |
| 5           | 1           | 2020-12-03   | 50000          |
| 6           | 1           | 2021-01-03   | 50000          |
| 7           | 1           | 2021-02-03   | 50000          |
| 8           | 1           | 2021-03-03   | 50000          |
| 9           | 1           | 2021-04-03   | 50000          |
| 10          | 1           | 2021-05-03   | 50000          |
| 11          | 1           | 2021-06-03   | 50000          |
+-------------+-------------+--------------+----------------+
```

I want to print this:

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| id_loan     | client      | date_loan   | amount_loan | amount_left |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1           | Robert      | 2020-07-01  | 3000000     | 2450000     |
| 2           | Michael     | 2021-07-12  | 2000000     | 2000000     |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Please note that Michael has a loan but has no payments yet.

I'm almost done with this query:

```
SELECT loans.id_loan,
   clients.name,
   loans.date_loan,
   loans.amount_loan,
   (loans.amount_loan-SUM(payments.amount_payment)) AS amount_left
FROM loans
LEFT JOIN clients ON loans.id_client = clients.id_client
LEFT JOIN payments ON loans.id_loan = payments.id_loan
```

But Michael is obviously not listed because he doesn't have a payment made yet.

Comment: I see nothing in your query that would keep someone with no payments from showing up; did you actually try it?

Comment: Yes, I already tested the query and it only returns clients with payments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a `GROUP BY loans.id_loan`, then the missing row should appear.  Also, I would suggest changing the JOIN on `clients` to just `JOIN`.

```
SELECT loans.id_loan,
   clients.name,
   loans.date_loan,
   loans.amount_loan,
   (loans.amount_loan-SUM(payments.amount_payment)) AS amount_left
FROM loans
JOIN clients ON loans.id_client = clients.id_client
LEFT JOIN payments ON loans.id_loan = payments.id_loan
GROUP BY loans.id_loan
```

DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32ca4/18

Comment: I wrote a message to say thanks to @Rocket Hazmat but someone deleted it  Thanks again Rocket Hazmat

Comment: @Lucho No prob.  Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

use a subselect to get the payments

```
SELECT loans.id_loan,
   clients.client_name,
   loans.date_loan,
   loans.amount_loan,
   (loans.amount_loan-IFNULL((SELECT SUM(payments.amount_payment) FROM payments WHERE id_loan      = loans.id_loan   ),0)) AS amount_left
FROM loans
LEFT JOIN clients ON loans.id_client = clients.id_client
```

[example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32ca4/26)

Comment: Thanks for your time but the answer of Rocket Hazmat is the correct way

Comment: @Lucho Mine is also correct see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32ca4/23

Comment: @nbk you need a coalesce around the subselect to make it subtract 0 instead of null when there are no payments

Comment: No, in your example i see null and null in both clients in the column amount_left

Comment: guys I really appreciate your answers but it is already resolved

Comment: Thanks @nbk for your time, now your approach is correct, I am also using IFNULL to return the loan_amount if the client has no payments, thanks again for your time